# Spring JPA + dynamically switch the datasource between schemas in postgresql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have to modify design of the existing application according to following manner,

[image]

According to above design each project contains it's own schema and that mapping table (project_schema_table) is under main schema. All schemas are under one Postgresql database and in future users will create another new schemas (on demand) for their new projects.

Before displaying login window I have to list all existing projects and once user select his project I have to direct to that project with relevant schema. Other than main schema all other project base schemas are exactly the same.

This is a desktop application developed with latest versions of java technologies JavaFX, Spring and JPA with Postgresql database. Currently it has only one project related schema and I have to introduce main schema and all other subsequent project base schemas.

I have found similar [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807366/dynamically-switching-databases-at-runtime-with-spring-4-hibernate-4-using-abs) but it didn't contains any solution. Whether I can accomplish this task with Spring [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) ? or is there any other mechanism. Thanks.

Comment: What is the ORM you are using below Spring JPA? Hibernate?

Comment: EntityManagerFactory use Hibernate as persistence provider. I am using Spring JPA repository feature with Spring-data-jpa version 1.4.2.RELEASE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called Multi-Tenancy and Hibernate supports this out of the box from version 4.x onwards. Please see this [post](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) on how to use this feature.

Comment: Hi Shazin. Thanks for feedback. Yes I got the idea how Multi Tenancy apply with SaaS. If you can please provide some example how it apply to this kind of multi schema J2EE application, that will be very helpful to me. Thanks.